# Room kotlin: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. Stuck on this error

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am getting two error

- error: Fields annotated with @Relation cannot be constructor parameters. These values are fetched after the object is constructed.
- error: Fields annotated with @Relation cannot be constructor parameters. These values are fetched after the object is constructed.

I have two table. One is **task table** and other is **sub-task table**. For every entity of task table, there are some entities of subtask table.

So I am trying to get all the task and the list of subtask fro individual task

Dao:

```
@Query("Select * from TaskTable")
fun getTasks():List<TaskModel>
```

TaskModel:

```
class TaskModel(
        @Embedded
        var taskTable: TaskTable,

        @Relation(parentColumn = "id",
                entityColumn = "taskId")
        var subTaskTable: List<SubTaskTable>
)
```

TaskTable:

```
@Entity
data class TaskTable(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id:Int = 0,
    var taskListId:Int = 0,
    var title: String,
    var details:String?
)
```

SubTaskTable:

```
@Entity
data class SubTaskTable (
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0,
    var taskId: Int = 0,

    var title: String,
    var details: String?)
```

build.gradle

```
//room
def room_version = "1.1.0"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room_version"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room_version"
// Test helpers
testImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$room_version"
```

And I apply **kotlin-kapt** plugin

Help me to fix this problem. I search on stack overflow and implement some answer but this not fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well it says they shouldn't be constructor parameters, so try making them not constructor parameters.

```
class TaskModel() {
    @Embedded
    lateinit var taskTable: TaskTable

    @Relation(parentColumn = "id",
              entityColumn = "taskId")
    lateinit var subTaskTable: List<SubTaskTable>
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, but what if I need a `data class`? Is there another way around this or just making the `@Embedded` attribute not a constructor parameter should sufied? I also updated to androidX since I read that there was a known bug in Room fixed on a new version released for androidX only

Comment: Well, [the example in docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#one-to-many) is a data class with `@Relation` parameter, see `UserWithPlaylists`. Is it a mistake?

Comment: @VadimKotov no, it's just that I wrote this answer in 2018.05.09, while the constructor arguments of data classes are supported since Room 2.1.0 which was release in 2019.06.13 (more than 1 year later), see https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.1.0 -- thanks for pointing it out though, apparently now you *can* use data classes like that.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I got the same error now while using POJO data class with Room 2.2.3. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used annotationProcesso instead of kapt and there were old version of room, please check the last version of room

kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

Comment: Thank you. I asked this question, maybe 2 years ago. And I also left android